# How to convert non-zero element of a sparse matrix to 1?

Tags: r, matrix

I have very huge sparse matrix. I need to convert non-zero element of that matrix to 1 and other entries left zero.
would someone help me to implement it in R ?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `m[m != 0] <- 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Using the sparse matrices from the `Matrix` package, I tried both jbaums' and Julien's methods, but I would get the following error in both:

`Error in if (any(i < 0L)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I found an alternative method that worked for me, and was very fast:

`m <- as(m!= 0, "dMatrix")`

`m != 0` produces a `lgCMatrix`, and converting it into a `dgCMatrix` through the method above will change all the `True` entries into 1, while leaving the `False` entries sparse.

If you were wondering how I found this, a similar example was in the R documentation for `lsparseMatrix-classes`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
yourMatrix[which(yourMatrix != 0)] <- 1
```

(What @jbaums propose is also working)

Comment: This is a bit quicker than subsetting the matrix directly with the logical vector (i.e. without `which`), as well.